# MySQL slow when using ORDER BY primary key

Tags: mysql

I was running into a problem with a seriously slow query (30+ seconds) on my MySQL 5.6 database. The query was of the form:

```
SELECT * from books 
where author_id = 14 
and publication_date < '2021-08-01' 
order by id desc limit 50
```

Where `id` is the primary key on the `books` table.

On this other hand, changing only the `ORDER BY` clause, this query:

```
SELECT * from books 
where author_id = 14 
and publication_date < '2021-08-01' 
order by publication_date desc limit 50
```

was returning results with acceptable speed.

Doing some investigating via `EXPLAIN`, I noticed that the first query uses `"key" : "PRIMARY",`, while the second one is using an index. Additionally, the second query shows
`"Extra" : "Using index condition; Using where"`, while the first just has `"Extra" : "Using where"`

I can understand that if the first query is not filtering the results using the index and instead has to sort *all* of the rows by `id`, it would not be able to return a result quickly. But I don't really understand why `ORDER BY` would be applied before filtering on the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` should *not* be happening before the filtering in the `WHERE` clause.  For the first query, I suggest adding an index which covers the majority of the query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON books (author_id, publication_date);
```

Note that InnoDB will, by default, include `id` at the end of the index.  This index completely covers the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  And it should be usable by both of your queries.

Comment: "ORDER BY should not be happening before the filtering in the WHERE clause."
Yes, that's exactly what I thought. Any insight into why it's happening here and not using the index? With a different `ORDER BY`, the query does use the index and thus goes much quicker.

Comment: Well you don't really have any index right now which covers well either query.  There is an explanation for the difference in performance, but the gist to understand is that MySQL will forgo using any index if it estimates that a table scan would perform better.  If you want MySQL to use an index, then craft it to the particular query.

Answer (score 0):

When presented with both a `WHERE` clause and an `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer makes a decision based on statistics that may be inadequate.  (Running `ANALYZE TABLE` may fix the stats, but I wouldn't hold my breath.)

The decision is between:

- focus on the `WHERE` in the hopes of whittling down the number of rows, leaving not too many to sort.
- focus on the `ORDER BY` and hope that it won't waste too much time filtering out unwanted (re: `WHERE`) rows.

Another complication is that you ask for `SELECT *`.  This implies that there is unlikely to be an index that "covers" all the columns needed.  (And this is an argument for never using `*`.)  This means that even if it can use an `INDEX`, it still must reach into the data's BTree to get the rest of the columns.

`SELECT *` plus `ORDER BY id (asc/desc)` gives a strong pull toward `PRIMARY`, since the data is in that order and the query cannot be run just in an `INDEX`.

In the second case, `INDEX(author_id, publication_date)` gives a strong pull toward using that `INDEX` since it completely covers the `WHERE` *and* the `ORDER BY`.

Unfortunately, the Optimizer does not seem to notice the `LIMIT` when making the decision.  (However, it may not have been able to make any use of it in this case.)  Note that the first case can stop after 50, but the second on may need to scan the entire rest of the table without finding 50.